# Setting up database for date dimension table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, data-warehouse

I was working on creating database for warehouse  purpose. I have many dimension table and one fact table. I have created separate `create_date` dimension table but It is not working as I want it to. Following is my data dimension table structure. I want to get date and in time hours, minutes and seconds

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS create_dates_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE "public"."create_dates" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('create_dates_id_seq'::regclass),
    "hours" int4,
    "minutes" int4,
    "seconds" int4,
    "date" date,
    "day" int4,
    "day_of_week" int4,
    "month" int4,
    "month_name" text,
    "quarter" int4,
    "quarter_name" text,
    "year" int4,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

I have used Big-int for relationship and I am using it in fact table as following

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."performances" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('performances_id_seq'::regclass),
    "responsetime" int4,
    "user_id" int8,
    "create_date_id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_7c33413662" FOREIGN KEY ("create_date_id") REFERENCES "public"."create_dates"("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_32824f66a5" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "public"."users"("id"),
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

But when I am relating these they are not working in Power BI I have also created relationship but it is not working only shows all data not one month data. I think I need to change this so now I want to make Datetime column as a primary key and relate both. Look like I am doing all wrong, can you advice me correct way to do it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! What are you "relating"? Try and put together a fiddle here ([sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9b9800570c583201df9e29051cfb1cc1))  which shows a problem! You could use some sample data to demonstrate what problem you're having!

Comment: Have you defined the relationship between the two tables in the PowerBI data model?  Just having the referential integrity in the database itself is not necessarily going to result in PowerBI knowing how the two tables relate.

Comment: While I hate to ask for an image, it's probably useful to see the two tables in the "Model" tab from PowerBI desktop.

Comment: well may be next time I dont' any place where I put image to share here. But I resolved it so put answer below, I break dimensions in time + date separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually incorrect design. The reason is we must break date dimension and table dimension separately. So I have split them now in following

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS create_dates_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE "public"."create_dates" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('create_dates_id_seq'::regclass),
    "date" date,
    "day" int4,
    "day_of_week" int4,
    "month" int4,
    "month_name" text,
    "quarter" int4,
    "quarter_name" text,
    "year" int4,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

And I created time dimension using following structure

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."dim_times" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "time" time,
    "hour" int2,
    "military_hour" int2,
    "minute" int4,
    "second" int4,
    "minute_of_day" int4,
    "second_of_day" int4,
    "quarter_hour" varchar,
    "am_pm" varchar,
    "day_night" varchar,
    "day_night_abbrev" varchar,
    "time_period" varchar,
    "time_period_abbrev" varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

and in my performance I have add both tables relationship

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."performances" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('performances_id_seq'::regclass),
    "responsetime" int4,
    "user_id" int8,
    "dim_time_id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "dim_date_id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_7c33413662" FOREIGN KEY ("create_date_id") REFERENCES "public"."create_dates"("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_32824f66a5" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "public"."users"("id"),
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

I also added more fields in my date dimension like holidays, weekend information and more details. This fix my issue now it is working. I am now using Integer as a key as no more BigInt needed.